# An effective way to perform a prefix search on ranked (sorted) list?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, kotlin, data-structures

I have a large list of some elements sorted by their probabilities:

```
data class Element(val value: String, val probability: Float)

val sortedElements = listOf(
    Element("dddcccdd", 0.7f),
    Element("aaaabb", 0.2f),
    Element("bbddee", 0.1f)
)
```

Now I need to perform a prefix searches on this list to find items that start with one prefix and then with the next prefix and so on (elements still need to be sorted by probabilities)

```
val filteredElements1 = sortedElements
                                  .filter { it.value.startsWith("aa") }

val filteredElements2 = sortedElements
                                  .filter { it.value.startsWith("bb") }
```

Each "request" of elements filtered by some prefix takes O(n) time, which is too slow in case of a large list.

If I didn't care about the order of the elements (their probabilities), I could sort the elements lexicographically and perform a binary search: sorting takes O(n*log n) time and each request -- O(log n) time.

Is there any way to speed up the execution of these operations without losing the sorting (probability) of elements at the same time? Maybe there is some kind of special data structure that is suitable for this task?

Comment: Why not two lists?

Answer (score 4):

You can read more about Trie data structure https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie 
This could be really useful for your usecase.

Leetcode has another very detailed explanation on it, which you can find here https://leetcode.com/articles/implement-trie-prefix-tree/

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes, I can you Trie to speedup the prefix search, but how can I keep my sorting (probabilities) when constructing a trie?

Comment: Your elements can be referenced from 2 data structures at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

If your List does not change often, you could create a `HashMap` where each existing Prefix is a `key` referring to a collection (sorted by probability) of all entries it is a prefix of.

getting all entries for a given prefix needs ~O(1) then.

Be careful the Map get really big. And creation of the map takes quite some time.